# MAMP download asking for .Net core 3.1 Runtime. Unsure which one to select

Tags: mamp

I was following a tutorial to download MAMP earlier, and I ran into this problem which wasn't explain in the tutorial. After I successfully downloaded MAMP, and I tried to open the application, it indicates that my computer do not have .Net Core 3.1 and I need to download it (directs me to this https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1/runtime?cid=getdotnetcore)

There are three options between: Run Console Apps with download x64 or download x86 / Run Desktop Apps with download x64 or download x86 / Run Server Apps with downloading hosting bundle. Which one is suitable?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the Run Desktop Apps x86 version, even if your system is x64.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the system type on your computer.
Here is a tutorial video that might help you to solve the error for installing .NET Core.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqYnexZwBPU&ab_channel=TroubleChute

Answer (score 0):

Installing the x86 version setup even though my system is x64 worked for me.